# Is Modifying Padding in Flutter's persistentFooterButtons Safe?

Tags: flutter, dart

Is it okay to modify Flutter native code? I have persistentFooterButtons that has padding of 8 around it, and I would like to use it without the original padding it has, is it fine? I did change it and made an apk release and it's working fine, but just a general question, is it okay or may I face issues or problems?

I removed the padding of 8 around it

Answer (score 0):

Not recommended to modify Flutter native code. The reason is that when you modify the native code, you might introduce side effects, and future updates to Flutter or related packages may conflict with your changes.
In your case when you remove padding around `persistentFooterButtons` it might work for now but look for alternative approaches like:

1. Look for open source package that does support this
2. Create custom widget for this